# аналог NVL на пустой выборке

Tags: postgresql

```
SELECT INTO _default_language COALESCE(s.code, 0) FROM language s WHERE s.code = 5;
```

Поскольку выборка пустая, то такой селект не делает ничего и _default_language остается неинициализированным и содержит NULL. ЕМНИП, оракловый NVL в данном случае бы выдал корректный результат _default_language = 0

Есть ли аналог ораклового nvl в постгре?

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test;
CREATE TABLE test
(
    code      INTEGER NOT NULL
);

DELETE FROM test;
INSERT INTO test(code) VALUES
  (0)
, (1)
, (2)
;

SELECT COALESCE(test.code, 3) FROM test WHERE code = 3;

SELECT COALESCE(test.code, 3) FROM test WHERE code = 3;
 coalesce 
----------
(0 rows)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь подзапросом:

```
SELECT INTO _default_language COALESCE((select s.code FROM language s WHERE s.code = 5), 0);
```

Или тоже самое в немного более императивном стиле:

```
_default_language := COALESCE((select s.code FROM language s where s.code = 5), 0);
```

Поведение `postgresql` мне кажется логичным, если условию не удовлетворяет ни одна строка - то пустая выборка в результате логична.

Comment: несмотря на общность диалектов, переход с оракла дается непросто :)